# does tensorflow 0.10.0rc version support float16?

Tags: tensorflow

In order to reduce the tensor, I defined all the variables with `dytpe=tf.float16` in my Model, and then defined the optimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
self.compute_gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(self.mean_loss_reg)
train_adam_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(self.compute_gradients, global_step=self.global_step)
```

Everything works ok! but after I run the train_adam_op, the the gradients and variables are nan in python. I wander If the `apply_gradients()` API supports `tf.float16` type? Why I got nan after `apply_gradients()` was called by `session.run()`....

Comment: after the `apply_gradients` operation executed, the `loss` became `nan` in python. So I suspect if tensorflow's `apply_gradients` API supports tf.float16 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dynamic range of fp16 is fairly limited compared to that of 32-bit floats. As a result, it's pretty easy to overflow or underflow them, which often results in the NaN that you've encountered.

You can insert a few check_numerics operations in your model to help pinpoint the specific operation(s) that becomes unstable when performed on fp16.

For example, you can wrap a L2 loss operation as follow to check that its result fits in an fp16

`A = tf.l2_loss(some_tensor)`

becomes

`A = tf.check_numerics(tf.l2_loss(some_tensor), "found the root cause")`

The most common source of overflows and underflows are the exp(), the log(), as well as the various classification primitives, so I would start looking there.

Once you've figured out which sequence of operations is problematic, you can update your model to perform that sequence using 32-bit floats by using tf.cast() to convert the inputs of the sequence to 32bit floats, and cast the result back to fp16.

Comment: Thank U very much! I'll have a try.

Comment: I added `tf.check_numerics()`  check for some operations in my model definition, but now I got the 'LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'training/loss/CheckNumerics' (op type: CheckNumerics)'  error. how to avoid this error? Could you please give me some advice

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved the problem. Using a `epsilon` parameter to the `apply_gradients()` API.

Comment: Is there any way to train a CNN using `tf.float16` or it is not is not possible at all ? The main reason I want to use `tf.float16` is that I want train complex networks so I am trying to reduce memory consummation.